# Get visible from jQuery collection of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code:

```
var filterInputs = $(this).siblings('.filterInputs');
```

which performs some work on filterInputs. Later on, I would like to reduce my collection of filterInputs to just those which are visible.

Clearly, I could do this:

```
var visibleFilterInputs = $(this).siblings('.filterInputs:visible');
```

but that seems inefficient given the fact that I already have a reference to the collection I was hoping to reduce.

Is there a way to say something like:

```
//TODO: Example
var visibleFilterInputs = $(filterInputs:visible);
```

without having to iterate over the DOM tree again? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right, there's no reason to recollect the DOM elements, since you already have them in a jQuery object. So that's exactly what the `.filter()` method is for: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Try this:

```
var visibleFilterInputs = filterInputs.filter(":visible");
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FC9sH/

Note that it's better to target a certain HTML tag, such as `<div>`, to make the `:visible` selector a little more efficient (since it isn't part of the CSS specs and can't be optimized by native methods). At least in your case, you're already using the `filterInputs` class. Anyways, maybe something like:

```
var visibleFilterInputs = filterInputs.filter("div:visible");
```

but **only** if that's applicable. I mean, even selecting multiple known element tags is probably better:

```
var visibleFilterInputs = filterInputs.filter("div:visible, p:visible");
```